# Finding the Oracle JDBC version using the command line

Tags: centos, oracle-database

I want to check out the Version of my Oracle JDBC driver.
In this case, I know the driver is 12.1.0.2:

```
/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/dbhome_1/bin/oracle
```

But without that I am searching for a valid command which will give me the version back on the console. I am using CentOS 7. Should I search for the `Manifest.MF` file or do you have other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle documents this in [Verifying a JDBC Client Installation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/java.817/a83724/getsta2.htm) with a sample function written in Java:

> If at any time you must determine the version of the JDBC driver that you installed, you can invoke the getDriverVersion() method of the OracleDatabaseMetaData class.

Further reading:

- [Oracle JDBC FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/jdbc-faq-090281.html)
- [Determine JDBC Driver Version](http://www.oracledistilled.com/java/determine-jdbc-driver-version/)  (giving the same advice)